# Azure DataFactory: Deployment Failed: At least one resource deployment operation failed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-data-factory

I am trying to deploy Azure Data Factory from development to Test and Production instances using Azure DevOps. The pipeline steps include:

1. Copying the Linked Templates to a storage account (Azure PowerShell Task).
2. Disabling the triggers (Azure PowerShell Task).
3. ARM Template Deployment (Azure Resource Group Deployment Task).
4. Enabling the Triggers (Azure PowerShell Task).

I have set the override parameters for Test and Production Tasks.
The deployment to the Test Data Factory completed successfully. However, when I tried deploying it to the Production Data Factory, it failed giving the following error :

```
There were errors in your deployment. Error code: DeploymentFailed.
2022-11-24T14:20:51.2337688Z ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
2022-11-24T14:20:51.2339819Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
2022-11-24T14:20:51.2340752Z ##[error]Details:
2022-11-24T14:20:51.2341700Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Details:
2022-11-24T14:20:51.2343511Z ##[error]DeploymentFailed: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
2022-11-24T14:20:51.2351532Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
2022-11-24T14:20:51.2352528Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
2022-11-24T14:20:51.2361768Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

I checked the steps for Test and Production tasks, and both seems correct to me. The Resource Group, Data Factory name, template parameters all have been set up.
How do I resolve this, since the error doesn't point to anything specific?

Comment: Could you please share your pipeline definition and ARM template demo after remove in-private information?

Comment: After a lot of troubleshooting, I found that the connection to the self-hosted integration runtime was not happening. So, I had to make that change and also the Production data factory had private endpoint enabled which was not the case for Test instance.

Comment: If you have a solution, please post an answer and [mark it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to end this question, this will help others who meet the similar situation. :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT I have posted the steps I followed to resolve my issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was with my connection to the Shared Integration Runtime for Data Factory.
So, the steps I followed were as follows :

1. In the Azure Portal, go to your Resource Group -> Activity Log
   [image]

2. Here, I found the exact cause of my Data Factory deployment failing.

```
Access denied. Unable to access shared integration runtime 'integrationRuntimeSelfHosted'. Please check whether this resource has been granted permission by the shared integration runtime.
```

3. Then I went to the Data Factory, where I had created the integration runtime and granted access to the new Data Factory which I was trying to deploy.
4. Go to Azure DevOps -> Deploy the Pipeline again.

Following the above steps helped me resolve my issue.

Comment: activity log was pointing me to the right direction, ty